# How can I increment an attribute's Value through my method? (python)

Tags: python, class, methods

I am trying to add my `update_number_served` method to my `increment_number_served` method in my code. I'm pretty confused with classes in general at this point but after much googling I can't seem to find the answer here as I am very new to python and stackoverflow:

```
class restaurant():
"""
A simple attempt to state a restaurant cuisine type and if it is open
using classes and functions
"""

    def __init__(self,restaurant_name,cuisine_type):
        """Initialize name and age attributes."""
        self.restaurant_name = restaurant_name
        self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type
        self.number_served = 0

    def describe_restaurant(self):
        """Simulate the restaurant cuisine type"""
        print(self.restaurant_name.title() + " contains " + self.cuisine_type.title() + " food.")

    def open_restaurant(self):
        """Simulate the restaurant open"""
        print(self.restaurant_name.title() + " is now open!")

    def update_number_served(self, number):
        self.number_served = number
        print("This restaurant has served " + str(number) + " customers.")

    def increment_number_served(self, number):
        self.number_served += number
        print("With a total of " + str(number))

restaurant_kravins = restaurant("Kravins", "jamaican")

restaurant_kravins.describe_restaurant()
restaurant_kravins.open_restaurant()
restaurant_kravins.update_number_served(10)
restaurant_kravins.increment_number_served(8)
```

Comment: what do you mean by "add my update_number_served method to my increment_number_served method"?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you should print `self.number_served` instead of the `number`, `number` is the number incremented, here `self.number_served += number` is equivalent to `self.number_served = self.number_served + number`.

```
def increment_number_served(self, number):
    self.number_served += number
    print("With a total of " + str(self.number_served))
```

For attributes with a `self.` before it, they are "visible" everywhere inside the `class`. So you can actually update it from another method. Like in this case, `self.number_served` is initially initialized in `__init__`, and assigned a value in `update_number_served`; and eventually updated in `increment_number_served`.

So, actually, after you call `restaurant_kravins.increment_number_served(8)`, the attribute `self.number_served` has already been updated. You can view it in the following way as well:

```
print('Total number served: ', restaurant_kravins.number_served)
```